# Java FX - non-expandable window

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I want to make a primary Stage a non-expandable window in JavaFX.
So, i don't want to widen or increase height, when i run my application.
I set size on anchor pane, which is my main layout, max sizes and minimum sizes. And this is not working.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set max i min size of your `Stage`:

```
primaryStage.setMaxHeight(height);
primaryStage.setMinHeight(height);
primaryStage.setMaxWidth(width);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(width);
```

or call

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```